# Find cell value on worksheet and copy all cell values from the last cell in the column with data to the top, excluding spaces

Tags: excel, vba

I can't get my copy to work correctly.  I need it to use the location of "A" cell as the starting cell to copy and then for .end(xlup) to look for cells from the bottom up to the "A" cell location and copy only cells with data into wbVer (omitting blank cells).

```
With wbVer.ws(1)
    for each ws in wbCs.sheets
If instr(1, ws.name, "value") then
     Set acell = ws.Cells.Find(What:=strPhone, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, _
     LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
     MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
If Not acell Is Nothing Then
     Set firstRange = wbkVer.ws("CSV").Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1,                             0).Resize(acell.Rows.Count, 1)
     Set rngCSPhcell = .Range(acell.Offset(1, 0)).End(xlUp).offset(-1,0)  '<---this isn't right
     rngCSPhcell.Copy
     firstRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End if
End if

End With
```

Comment: You have a `For each ws` loop inside a `With wbVer.ws(1)` block. That looks like potential for error. How is `ws` dimensioned?

Comment: It would also be a good idea to remove the `On Error Resume Next` which does nothing but pretend the errors aren't happening, and likely result in further errors.

Comment: +1 for the error messages. you need them while developing .. after that do all the error handling you want.
Also .. I cant really find what the issue is without looking at the data..try stepping through the debugger while using the watch window to follow how the variables you assign are changing. VBA has an awesome debugger use it!

Comment: `.End(xlUp)` will stop at the first blank cell. That might be part of the problem when setting the range variable `rngCSPhCell`.

Comment: Removed the On error resume next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing more of your code or the worksheet, this is all I can suggest:

Dimension these variables in addition to whatever you already have:

```
Dim aCell As Range
Dim rngToCopy As Range      'Use this to contain the ENTIRE range of cells to be copied
Dim cl As Range
Dim c As Long: c = 1
```

Then, starting with `If Not aCell is Nothing`, replace your code with the following:

```
If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
'Commented out per revision:'
    'Set rngToCopy = Range(Cells(1, aCell.Column).Address, Cells(aCell.Row, aCell.Column).Address)  '
    Set rngToCopy = Range(acell.Offset(1, 0), Range("A1048576").End(xlUp))

    'Assuming this evaluates to a single cell range...
    'find the next empty cell in column A of wbkVer.ws("CSV")
    Set firstRange = wbkVer.ws("CSV").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) '<< Set this Range to the FIRST cell address that you want to paste to.

    For Each cl In rngToCopy
        'If statement to ignore blank cells:
        If Not cl.Value = vbNullString Then
            'This puts the cell's value in firstRange, row "c", column 1.'
            'Adjust as necessary.'
            'assuming firstRange is a single cell, we can just use .Offset with the '
            ' incrementer variable, "c":
            firstRange.Offset(c, 0).Value = cl.Value
            c = c + 1
        End If
    Next
End If
```

Note that I'm not sure how you're trying to set `aCell` so this line may need to be modified:

`Set rngToCopy = Range(Cells(1, aCell.Column).Address, Cells(aCell.Row, aCell.Column).Address)`

Right now, it should be setting `rngToCopy` as the range of cells in `aCell`'s column, from row 1 to whatever row `aCell` is in.

Comment: Thanks David!  This looks to be what I'm looking for, I'll try it out and reply shortly.

Comment: Ok almost there!  Although, from where acell is identified I need to offset(1,0) and the range will be from the bottom, up to the acell offset (excluding empty cells).  Make sense?

Comment: Example: If acell is A3, offset to A4 and the .end(xlup) cell is A89.  So, from  A89 up to and including A3 needs to be copied (and checking for blank cells while It's establishing the copy/paste range).  If that's too much of a pain, then A89 to A3 whole range is fine.

Comment: `Range("A4").End(xlUp)` can *never* be "A89". You'd have to use `.End(xlDown)` for that.  In a pinch you could just `Set rngToCopy = Range("A3:A89")`.  It is important to note that neither `xlUp` or `xlDown` will ever take you past a blank cell, so if you have `aCell = Range("A3")` and there is a blank cell in `A16`, then that's where `xlDown` will stop, and you'll end up with an incomplete range.

Comment: OK try again. made revision to the `Set rngToCopy`

Comment: The .Range("A1048576")  isn't correct.  The column will be dynamic based on where acell is located.  Sorry, I forgot to add that. :(

Comment: It sounds like you can figure it out at this point... why don't you try. Let me know if you get stuck.

Comment: Set rngToCopy = Range(acell.Offset(1, 0), Range("A1048576").End(xlUp)) ----  The first part ID's the cell I'm looking for and I get that and see it VBA.  The second part needs to find the last cell in the ID'd cell's column, which I don't get... :(   Range((acell.Offset(1, 0))).Column.End(xlUp)) makes sense, but I get an invalid qualifier error.